# Yii's default ajax is not working

Tags: ajax, yii

In my Yii application, Yii's default Ajax is not working. Also default Ajax validation is not working. Has this been an installation problem or any other problem. How to enable Yii's default Ajax. 
In my controller,

```
 public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Company;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if (isset($_POST['Company'])) {
        $company = Company::model()->findAll();
        if (count($company) === 0) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['Company'];
            $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'logo');
            if (isset($uploadedFile)) {
                $fileName = date('Ymdhis') . '_' . $uploadedFile->name;  // $timestamp + file name
                $model->logo = $fileName;
            }
            if ($model->validate()) {
                if ($model->save()) {
                    if (isset($uploadedFile)) {
                        $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../banner/' . $fileName);
                    }
                    $this->redirect(array('create'));
                }
            }
        } else {
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', 'Company details is already exists.');
        }
    }

    $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

In view page,

```
  <?php
                $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                    'id' => 'company-form',
                    'enableClientValidation' => true,
                    'clientOptions' => array(
                        'validateOnChange' => true,
                        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                    ),
                    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
                    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
                    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
                    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
                    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
                ));
                ?>

 <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $form->label($model, 'company_name', array('class' => 'req')); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'company_name', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'company_name', array('class' => 'school_val_error')); ?>
                </div>
```

Please help me.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Yii has no default `AJAX`. This is a technology based on `JavaScript` language. By default Yii includes a `jQuery` library which provided some methods for easy manipulations with `AJAX`. If you want use it on your page, you should add this string:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');
```

You can add this string to your main layout, for example into top of /views/layouts/main.php`

Comment: By using this code, Getting error like "CClientScript and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "registerCore". ".

Comment: @Arya please update your question and provide controller, model and view code.

Comment: Open a browser console and check whether AJAX request sends to server while you fill the form.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that, But not sending Ajax request to the server.

Comment: @Arya try to remove `'enableClientValidation' => true,` may be it block ajax validation

Comment: I tried, But not working Ajax. Not only Ajax validation any type of Ajax requests like dependent dropdown etc.. are not working. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108126/discussion-between-arya-and-size).